# Eclipse Collections, prepend immutable list

Tags: prepend, eclipse-collections

How to prepend (ideally `O(1)`) to an immutable List (of Eclipse Collections)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `ImmutableList` that you can prepend to with o(1) behavior in Eclipse Collections today, but you might be able to use an `ImmutableStack` for similar behavior depending on what you are trying to do.

```
ImmutableStack<Integer> stack = Stacks.immutable.empty();
stack = stack.push(1);
stack = stack.push(2);
stack = stack.push(3);
Assert.assertEquals(Stacks.immutable.with(1, 2, 3), stack);

// Eclipse Collections 10.x
ImmutableList<Integer> list1 = stack.toList().toImmutable();
Assert.assertEquals(Lists.immutable.with(3, 2, 1), list1);

// Eclipse Collections 11.x
ImmutableList<Integer> list2 = stack.toImmutableList();
Assert.assertEquals(Lists.immutable.with(3, 2, 1), list2);
```